# Unable to upgrade iOS 13 for my 5th gen Ipad

Tags: ipad, install, software-update, software, ipados

[image]

My iPad is a 5th generation iPad. From what I know it should be able to use iOS 13.

However, I have refreshed a few times in settings and it just says it is up to date to the latest iOS 12 version.

How can I make the iPad updated to the latest iOS 13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you've got mixed up between iOS 13 and iPadOS.

While iOS 13 has now been released to the public, iPadOS isn't available until 24 September 2019.

Comment: Also note that iOS 13 is buggy as hell, I would assume iPadOS could be the same. I would hold off upgrading until at least the first x.1 update